# Switching Between Two Activities Without Starting New Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, back

Lets say I have a three Activities (Activity A) - (Activity B) - (Activity C) and I am switching  between them respectively. A to B, B to C . What I want to do is after making three passes ( A->B->C ) Back to B from C and then pass again from B to C without starting new Activity. I know how to back to Home (C->A) and make a single back (C->B). I Hope I made my self clear. Is there a way to make the transition B from C just like using finish() method.

Comment: Just cache the image. By default even rotating the screen creates a new activity.

Comment: I agree with @kabuko, you don't need to persist the whole activity, just cache the image.

Comment: I'am caching the image still I dont want to start New activity.It takes time anyway. I want to pass C from B just like using finish() method and pass back to C from B.

Comment: then finish A from begining.

Comment: what does it mean ? finish A from begining

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the various flags which can be used in an `Intent` when starting a new `Activity`.

One or more of the following may do what you want...

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

Answer (score 0):

To not create extra instances of an Android activity, the following line to the AndroidManifest.xml inside your activity tag.

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Other than “singleTop”, the other ones are “standard”, “singleTop”, and “singleInstance”. [More info here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)